# Combine $push and save in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Writing my pet application I met some problem. I'm using nodejs and mongojs library to work with mongo.
I wrote code:

```js
  db.users.findOne({_id: ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Can not find name for user.');
      return;
    }

    userName = doc.userName;

    db.notes.findOne({userId: id}, function (err, doc) {
      if (!doc) {
        db.notes.insert({
          userId: id,
          userName: userName,
          notes: [req.body]
        }, function (err, doc) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send('Server error.');
            return;
          }

          res.json(doc);
        });
      } else {
        db.notes.update({
          userId: id
        }, {
          $push: {
            'notes': req.body
          }
        },
        function (err, doc) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send('Server error.');
            return;
          }

          res.json(doc);
        });
      }

      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Server error.');
        return;
      }
    });
  });
```

Now it looks like callback hell for me. I try to modify my code to make it more readable and use save method:

```js
  users.findOne({_id: makeObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Can not find name for user.');
      return;
    }

    userName = doc.userName;

    notes.save({
      userId: id,
      userName: userName
    }, {
      $push: {
        'notes': req.body
      }
    }, function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error during inserting the note');
      }

      res.status(200).send(doc);
    });
  });
```

Now it looks more readable but doesn't work. Is it possible in MongoDB to combine save method (to make it possible to modify document if it exists and create new if not) and $push for one of parameters?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You actually want [`.update()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update) or even [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) and then of course the ["upsert"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) option as is shown in the core documentation.

Comment: Thank you for answering . Could you be so kind to provide code with push. I'm not sure I understand how to implement it with .update().

Comment: Not clear what you are "adding to the array". Particularly in conjuntion with "upsert" there is an important distinction between whether this is an [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operation or a more complex multi-update operation.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo!!!

```js
notes.update({
      userId: id,
    }, {
      $set: {
        userId: id,
        userName: userName
      },
      $push: {
        notes: req.body
      }
    }, {
      upsert: true
    }, function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error during inserting the note');
      }
      res.status(200).send(doc);
    });
```

Thanks to [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven)